# Calling annotate_text from IBM Watson Concept Insights with Python

Tags: python, python-requests, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, concept-insights

I wrote a set of Python functions to interact with the Bluemix/Watson [Concept Insights API](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/concept-insights.html). I am able to generate a token and use it to get a result from the server, but the result stinks: it's nowhere near as good as what I get when I plug the same information into their [Swagger testing utility](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/swagger.html?url=/listings/concept-insights-v2.json#!/graphs/annotateText).

I suspect that something is wrong with the way I am sending my request, but I don't know quite what. The code follows. First, from `event_insight_lib.py`:

```
def importCredentials(filename='credentials.json'):
    if filename in [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]:
        data = json.load(open(filename))['concept_insights'][0]['credentials']
        return data

def generateToken(filename='credentials.json'):
    credentials = importCredentials(filename)
    r = requests.get("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token\?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights/api", auth=(credentials['username'], credentials['password']))
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        return r.text

def annotateText(text, token, content_type = 'text/plain'):
    base_url='https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/concept-insights/api/v2/graphs/wikipedia/en-20120601/annotate_text'
    headers = {'X-Watson-Authorization-Token': token, 'Content-Type': content_type}
    r = requests.post(base_url, headers=headers, data={'body': text})
    return r.text
```

These methods are executed by `event_insight.py`:

```
token = event_insight_lib.generateToken()
ret = event_insight_lib.annotateText("""long string being concept-analyzed...""", token)
    print(ret)
```

A full demonstration of the difference in output is [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/233701/why-is-there-such-a-large-difference-between-simul.html). The full codebase is [here](https://github.com/ResidentMario/py-events). I'm not very experienced with the Requests library: is there a subtle mistake somewhere on the Pythonic end?

The relevant part of IBM's documentation is [here](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-tokens.shtml).

Comment: You're passing a dict in the `data` parameter of your request, which is going to form encode the data. Try passing just `data=text`. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: You are right! Changing that segment to `data=text.encode(encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore')` appears to have fixed the issue.

Comment: We have a Python SDK that we are working on.Concept Insights is not supported there but I will hopefully next week. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk

Comment: That's great to know!

A small question, since you're here: are tokens meant to be reused? I've been generating a new one for every request but the documentation says they live for an hour.

Comment: You don't need tokens, you can use Basic Auth with a username and password. Tokens are made to be use client-side or with the speech to text websockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @engineerc suggested you are sending a `dict()` as `data`. Quoting your comment `data=text.encode(encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore')` is the solution for your problem.

---

On the other hand, please **don't use** `https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net`, it's a proxy application we use to host the swagger documentation.
The service url is:
`https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights/api`

Also, we have a python-sdk that supports [`ConceptInsights`](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/concept-insights.html) and the `annotate_text` call.

It's a pip module so you will do:

```
pip install watson-developer-cloud
```

Calling `annotate_text` it's as simple as:

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ConceptInsightsV2 as ConceptInsights


concept_insights = ConceptInsights(
    username='YOUR SERVICE USERNAME',
    password='YOUR SERVICE PASSWORD')

annotations = concept_insights.annotate_text('IBM Watson won the Jeopardy television show hosted by Alex Trebek')
print(json.dumps(annotations, indent=2))
```

Comment: Thanks---I will hopefully get to updating [watsongraph](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watsongraph/) (the product of all of this probing) to using `watson-developer-cloud` sometime in the next month or so.